# Lookup Edit binding

Tags: entity-framework, devexpress

I have a model written using Entity Framework Code First called **Project**.

In my **UI**, there is a page called **ProjectEdit** as shown in the image below. As seen in the image below, `Customer` and `BOMs` are `Lookup Edit`.

[image]

I'm trying to load `Customer` and `BOMs` to `Lookup Edit` but it's not working. Below is my code.

```
//New
if (entity == null)
    {
        Entity = new Project();
    }

//Edit
else
    {
        ProjectCodeTextEdit.DataBindings.Add("EditValue", entity, "ProjectCode");
        DescriptionTextEdit.DataBindings.Add("EditValue", entity, "Description");
        CustomerLookUpEdit.DataBindings.Add("EditValue", entity, "CustomerId");
        BOMsLookUpEdit.DataBindings.Add("EditValue", entity, "BOMs");
    }
```

Below is my LookUpEdit Properties.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Generally LookUpEdit object's data binding is not implemented the same way as a TextEdit object's. While in TextEdits's case you just need to assign the variable value to EditValue property (I suppose your TextEdits binding work fine, isn't it?), with LookUp Edit you should assign variables to ValueMember and a DisplayMember properties of the object. That is why we usually display data rows with LookUpEdit objects, where ValueMember is the identification field of the row and DisplayMember is the field of the row whose value you wish to be displayed.

In your case you should be more clear about what you wish to display in your lookupedits. Each Project instance has one Customer property and many BOMs, right? So CustomerLookUpEdit will show one record and BOMsLookUpEdit a list of values according to the Project object that was chosen for edit, correct? I suppose that both your Customer and BOM classes have some kind of ID property and description property of their own. In this case you should bind these values to the LookUpEdits. eg. in your initialization function code add these lines

```
CustomerLookUpEdit.Properties.DataSource = entity.Customer;
CustomerLookUpEdit.Properties.ValueMember = "someCustomerIDpropertyName" ;
CustomerLookUpEdit.Properties.DisplayMember = "someCustomerDescriptionpropertyName";

BOMsLookUpEdit.Properties.DataSource = entity.BOMs;
BOMsLookUpEdit.Properties.ValueMember = "someBOMIDpropertyName" ;
BOMsLookUpEdit.Properties.DisplayMember = "someBOMDescriptionpropertyName" ;
```

You can read more in this topic https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/clsDevExpressXtraEditorsLookUpEdittopic

Comment: I've tried the solution mentioned above. Also, I've tried using the LookUp Edit Properties that I've added in my question. Unfortunately, it didn't work.

Comment: I've solved the problem. I think this is due to Entity Framework. In `CustomerLookUpEdit.Properties.DataSource = entity.Customer;` line, `entity.Customer` has to be replaced with `entity.Customer.ToList()`

Comment: Actually you are right, I think the DataSource object must implement IList or IListSource interface so even if you have only one customer, it must be added as a List

Answer (score 0):

When we are adding entities to a List, we have to take care of our DataSource if is a DBContext or a DBSet, each one has implications in the compiler, that was your case, in this case you had to especify your DataSource like a DBSet and get the Entities

```
Add<TEntity>(TEntity entity)
```

The type parameter omitted is posible because the compiler will infer it.